# Animated bitmaps with 2 colours only

Tags: animation, raster-image, bitmap-graphics

I want to create an animated GIF, but instead of 8-bit 256 colours, my data is comprised of binary bitmaps of black/white pixels.

Can GIF accommodate this, or are pixels in GIF always 8-bit indices?

I need the resulting GIF to be small in size, so I cannot afford to waste 7 of the 8 bits.

If GIF does not support this, is there any other file format that would allow me to do this?

I believe that TIFF supports 1-bit images, but I've never seen an animated TIFF file.

Comment: "*I need the resulting GIF to be small in size, so I cannot afford to waste 7 of the 8 bits.*" What makes you think that is what would happen? GIF uses *compression*, not just paletting. Maybe you should compress your image with GIF and see if it is "too big" for you.

Comment: It's been a *very* long time (cough ~35 years) since I was experimenting with writing a GIF compressor, but IIRC, if the colour table has between 2^(N-1)+1  and 2^N entries, then I *think* it will initially use N bits to index into that table (and gradually increase as it builds up strings of symbols).  ...  but take with a grain of salt.